# Trouble shooting robust regression model created from a OLS model in Statsmodel

Tags: python, statistics, regression, statsmodels, robust

I am having trouble running a robust regression model with Statsmodel in python.

The following OLS model works:

```
model_name = sm.ols(formula="depenent ~ var1 * var2 + var3", data=data).fit()
```

I tried running:

```
model_name= sm.RLM(formula="depenent ~ var1 * var2 + var3", data=data).fit()
```

but I get the following type error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'endog' and 'exog'
```

I read through this documentation:
https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/rlm.html but am still struggling with the code. I am open to using another package such as Scikit

Thank you.

Comment: You should include the error message -- or explain more what you mean by "but it did not work"

Comment: fixed, thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ols` version should not work if `sm` is `statsmodels.api`. `statsmodels.api` only has `OLS` (capital letters for class name)

The formula functions are lower case, i.e. `rlm` imported from `statsmodels.formula.api`. This is just an alias of the class method `RLM.from_formula`.

RLM in capital letters is the name of the class which does not support formulas directly, and requires either numpy arrays or pandas DataFrames or Series.

see for example http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/formulas.html

Note `the formula.api` lower case objects are simply defined as aliases, e.g. for OLS/ols and RLM/rlm

```
import statsmodels.regression.linear_model as lm_
import statsmodels.robust.robust_linear_model as roblm_

ols = lm_.OLS.from_formula
rlm = roblm_.RLM.from_formula
```

Comment: How do you print out r^2, adjusted r^2, and f-test data? Thanks.

Comment: (That's a different question.) statsmodels RLM does not have those. wald_test can be used to compute the joint hypothesis test for the slope coefficient. I never looked at Rsquared for RLM but I guess it could be defined in analogy to WLS but it's currently not computed.