# Python Logistic Regression (PatsyError: model is missing required outcome variables)

Tags: python, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I was running my code below and keep getting the PatsyError: model is missing required outcome variables.

It was fine when I ran it with the formula notation

```
logit_model = sm.logit('y ~ age+default+balance+housing+loan+duration+campaign+pdays+previous', data = train_data).fit()
```

but when I try it again with the np array notation, I keep getting the error

```
logit_model = sm.logit(X_train, Y_train).fit()
```

Here is my full code

```
bank = pd.read_csv("C:/Bank.csv")
bank.isnull().sum()

#convert to binary
bank[bank.select_dtypes(['object']).columns]=bank.select_dtypes(['object']).apply(lambda x: x.astype('category'))
bank.replace(to_replace={'y': {'no':0,'yes':1} },inplace=True)
bank[bank.select_dtypes(['object']).columns]=bank.select_dtypes(['object']).apply(lambda x: x.astype('category'))
bank.replace(to_replace={'default': {'no':0,'yes':1} },inplace=True)
bank[bank.select_dtypes(['object']).columns]=bank.select_dtypes(['object']).apply(lambda x: x.astype('category'))
bank.replace(to_replace={'loan': {'no':0,'yes':1} },inplace=True)
bank[bank.select_dtypes(['object']).columns]=bank.select_dtypes(['object']).apply(lambda x: x.astype('category'))
bank.replace(to_replace={'housing': {'no':0,'yes':1} },inplace=True)


bankx = bank[["age","default","balance","housing","loan","duration","campaign","pdays", "previous"]]
banky = bank["y"]

X = np.array(bankx)
Y = np.array(banky)

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size=0.25)


logit_model = sm.logit(X_train, Y_train).fit()
```

Comment: Logit is not logit. Look at the difference between statsmodels.formula.api and lowercase names versus statsmodels.api and uppercase class names. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54545341/trouble-shooting-robust-regression-model-created-from-a-ols-model-in-statsmodel/54545874#54545874

Comment: I'm using statsmodels.formula.api

Comment: When you use arrays or DataFrames instead of formulas, then you cannot use the formula.api.

Answer (score 0):

First using an example dataset:

```
import seaborn as sns

data = sns.load_dataset("iris")
data['target'] = (data['species'] == "versicolor").astype("float")

data.head()
   sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width species  target
0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa       0
1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa       0
2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa       0
3           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  setosa       0
4           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  setosa       0
```

If you want to use a formula, you call the [statsmodel formula api](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/example_formulas.html) which is what you did, and you can get a summary of the results:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
mod = smf.logit(formula='target ~ sepal_length + petal_length', data=data)
res = mod.fit()
# you get a summary of the results
res.summary()
```

You can use the numpy array or pandas dataframe, and you need to call `Logit` from `statsmodels.api` as opposed to the formula interface above:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

X = data[['sepal_length','petal_length']]
y = data['target']
mod = sm.Logit(y, X)
res.summary()
```